# Hοw do i adjust the font size of all pages using ion-range in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

How can Ι change font size of all pages using ion-range. Τhis code works only in my home page.

home.component.html

```
<ion-range min="1" max="6"  snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="fontSize"> </ion-range>
```

home.component.ts

```
fontSize: number;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I post [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/haw-do-i-change-the-font-size-of-all-pages-using-ion-range-in-ionic-4/185722?u=kawarien) if it can help someone